# Web Image Scraping not giving any output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the photos in the URL below, but this code doesn't give any output, why?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

url = 'https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/Ljubljana--Slovenia/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=Ljubljana%2C%20Slovenia&place_id=ChIJ0YaYlvUxZUcRIOw_ghz4AAQ&checkin=2020-11-01&checkout=2020-11-08&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click'
 r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')

print(images)
for image in images:
 name = image['alt']
 link = image['src']
 print(name, link)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: Your request doesn't return any `img`. I think that the main problem is that the actual web page relies on JS rendering the data when accessed in browser. So my suggestion for you is to look into selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
# Replace this with the website's URL
URL = "put your URL here"
getURL = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
print(getURL.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(getURL.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')
resolvedURLs = []

for image in images:
    src = image.get('src')
    resolvedURLs.append(requests.compat.urljoin(URL, src))

for image in resolvedURLs:
    webs = requests.get(image)
    open('images/' + image.split('/')[-1], 'wb').write(webs.content)
```